# Multiple rendering problem and how can I use the useEffect here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, console.log

Filtering data by using this function, if I am calling this function in useEffect than its pushes to search results and not working well.

```
const AdvanceSearch = (props) => {
  
  const [region, setRegion] = useState("");  
  const [searchStuhl, setSearchStuhl] = useState("");    
      const filterData = (async ()=> {
     const filtereddata = await props.data.filter((item) => {
            return (
                item.region.toLowerCase().includes(region.toLowerCase())             
              && item.stuhl.toLowerCase().includes(searchStuhl.toLowerCase())             
          )}    
      ) await props.history.push({
            pathname: '/searchResults/',
            state:
            {
                data:filtereddata
            }
        })
  })

  //If the props. history.push is pass here instead of the above function then its sending the empty array and not the filtered data

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
      await filterData();      
     
    }
```

Comment: add your useEffect function also here. please show the complete peace of logic for data filter

Answer (score 1):

when you are changing the navigation URL with some data and there is multiple rendering then the following problem would be there.

- Check your route configuration for the path. is it configured to hold the changed path: in this scenario, you get fluctuated UI or we can say multiple renders
- yes you can use useEffect hooks to change the path and set the data here is the peace of code. here  whenever your props.data will be changed filteredData will run and it will return the value when data will be available.

```js
const filteredData = useCallback(() => {
   if(props.data){
   const filteredData = props.data.filter((item) => (
    item.region.toLowerCase().includes(region.toLowerCase())
    &&item.stuhl.toLowerCase().includes(searchStuhl.toLowerCase()) 
   ));
   return filteredData
  }
}, 
[props && props.data]);

useEffect(()=> {
  const data = filteredData();
  if(data){
    props.history.push({
    pathname:'/search-results',
    state:{data}
    });
  }
},[filteredData])
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but the problem is still there. Now on the search tab, its redirect it to the search results without opening the search page. Especially when i am adding the filtered data function in to use Effect

Comment: in that condition the logic of useEffect would be associated with some search button etc. so that it will stay on the page untill someone doesn't hit that button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove async / await from the function. You don't need them to filter an array.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but the problem is not solved